# Getting blank value for radio button

Tags: php, html

Trying to receive which radio button is checked in my PHP through Post but for some reason, I am getting no value. Does anyone else see where I am going wrong? The form is submitted through javascript after some validation. I can provide that code if needed.

Button group HTML:

```
<!-- Start Purchase Radio -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="transType" id="transTypePurchase" value="purchase">
                Purchase
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Purchase Radio -->

<!-- Start Refinance Radio -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="transType" id="transTypeRefinance" value="refinance">
                Refinance
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Refinance Radio -->

<!-- Start Transfer Radio -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="radio">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="transType" id="transTypeTransfer" value="transfer">
                Transfer
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Transfer Radio -->

<!-- Start Other Radio -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input" name="transType" id="transTypeOther">
            </span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button" name="transType" id="transcationOtherText" onfocus="otherTextBox(transcationOtherText);" placeholder="Other">
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Other Radio -->
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['transType'])) {
    $value = $_POST['transType'];
    echo "*" . $value . "*";
}
```

Comment: What is the contents of your text input of the same name? I believe it will always use the contents of the input box as it's the last element on the page with that name

Comment: Does `print_r($_POST);` contain other expected key/values?

Comment: Thanks all for your quick responses! The answer is below. It was the name of my "other" text field is the same as the radios. Once I changed it I got the radio value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have same name as radio input for text input. See

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button" name="transType" id="transcationOtherText" onfocus="otherTextBox(transcationOtherText);" placeholder="Other">
```

Change the name of above input.

Comment: That was it...Spent 2 hours trying to figure that out. Will mark it as the correct answer when the timer is up. Thank you.